# Função encode() e criação de hashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, encode

Estou utilizando o Python 3.6 para fazer um programa no qual a pessoa digita um hash MD5, então o programa salva o hash em uma variável, lê um arquivo txt e joga o conteúdo dentro de uma lista, onde cada nome separado por `,` seja um item dessa lista.

Depois disso, o programa entra em um loop onde ele encripta para item da lista (txt) e compara com o hash digitado. Se a comparação for `True`, então ele descobre a palavra que está ali no hash.

Segue o código:

```
passmd5 = input("Digite o hash MD5: ")  #dega a hash desejada

lista = open('worldlist.txt', "r") #abre o arquivo txt
worldlist = lista.read() #ler todo conteúdo como uma string
worldlist = worldlist.split(", ") #Quebra a string por palavras separadas por ', '
descripto = hashlib.md5() #Variável que será utilizada para criptografar cada item da lista

for item in worldlist: #loop que percorre cada item da lista
    descripto.update(item.encode('utf-8')) #caso eu nao use o encode, o python retorna o seguinte erro: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
    if descripto.hexdigest() == passmd5: #Verifico se o item criptografado é igual ao hash passado, se sim, descubro a palavra
        print ("-----------------------------------")
        print ("Sua Hash MD5: ", passmd5)
        print ("Hash Descriptograda: ", item)
    print (descripto.hexdigest())
    print (item)
```

Uso os dois prints do final para ver como está a saída, pois a comparação do `if` não está funcionando.

Percebi que quando dou um `print(item)` a saída é o item da `worldlist` de forma correta, mas quando uso o `print(item.encode("utf-8"))` um `b` é adicionado na frente do item, ficando assim: `b'fulano'`. Então, acredito que é por isso que a comparação nunca dá certo, ele compara `fulano` com `b'fulano'`. (Criptografado, é claro!)

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar a fazer funcionar e também dar uns toques em relação ao código, pois estou aprendendo.

Comment: Uma dica é usar `with` quando for manipular arquivos, pois ele já fecha o arquivo automaticamente: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo seu código, estou assumindo que você está usando o [módulo `hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/hashlib.html).

O problema é que o método `update`, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update), é acumulativo: chamar `update(a)` e em seguida `update(b)` é equivalente a chamar `update(a+b)`. Por exemplo:

```
import hashlib

md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update(b'a')
print(md5.hexdigest()) # hash de 'a'
md5.update(b'b')
print(md5.hexdigest()) # hash de 'ab'
```

Primeiro eu chamo `update` com `a`, e depois com `b`. Como as chamadas de `update` são acumulativas, o resultado final é o hash de `ab`. A saída deste código é:

```
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
187ef4436122d1cc2f40dc2b92f0eba0
```

O primeiro é o hash de `a`, e o segundo, de `ab`. Chamar `update` com `a` e depois com `b` é o mesmo que fazer uma única chamada com `ab`:

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update(b'ab')
print(md5.hexdigest())
```

Este código também imprime `187ef4436122d1cc2f40dc2b92f0eba0`.

Apenas para comparar, para saber o hash de somente `b`:

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update(b'b')
print(md5.hexdigest())
```

O resultado é `92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f`.

---

Como você criou sua variável `descripto` fora do *loop*, as chamadas de `update` estão sendo acumuladas, então o hash sendo calculado não é de cada uma das palavras, e sim de todas as palavras sendo concatenadas.

Na primeira iteração do *loop*, `update` é chamado com a primeira palavra. Na segunda iteração, `update` é chamado com a segunda palavra, mas como este método é acumulativo, o hash resultante será da primeira palavra concatenada com a segunda. E assim por diante...

A solução é construir novamente o objeto a cada iteração:

```
for item in worldlist:
    descripto = hashlib.md5() # criar um novo md5
    descripto.update(item.encode('utf-8'))
    ...
```

---

Você pode ver a diferença neste exemplo:

```
words = ['teste', 'teste', 'teste']
# criar md5 fora do loop
md5 = hashlib.md5()
for item in words:
    md5.update(item.encode('utf-8'))
    print(md5.hexdigest())
```

Eu criei uma lista que contém 3 vezes a mesma palavra. Então o resultado deveria ser o mesmo hash impresso 3 vezes, certo? Errado:

```
698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
f6fd1939bdf31481d27ac4344a2aab58
1ceae7af21732ab80f454144a414f2fa
```

O primeiro hash corresponde a `teste`. O segundo hash corresponde a `testeteste`, já que as chamadas de `update` são acumulativas. E o terceiro hash corresponde a `testetesteteste`.

Criando um novo `md5` a cada iteração do loop traz o resultado correto:

```
for item in words:
    md5 = hashlib.md5() # criar md5 a cada iteração
    md5.update(item.encode('utf-8'))
    print(md5.hexdigest())
```

Como estou criando um novo `md5` a cada iteração do `for`, as chamadas de `update` não se acumulam, e o resultado é o hash de `teste` impresso 3 vezes:

```
698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b
```

---

Sobre a sintaxe `b'etc'`, a [resposta do @Sidon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353608/112052) já explica bem o que é.

Vale lembrar também que [hash **não** é o mesmo que criptografia](http://ctankersley.com/2009/10/14/hashing-is-not-encryption/), e o MD5 já é [considerado um algoritmo "obsoleto"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2994).

Comment: Cara, perfeito! Muito obrigado mesmo, já teste e já funcionou. Obrigado também pelas dicas no final da sua resposta, eu sinceramente não sábia.

Answer (score 3):

Dá "uns toques em relação ao código" ficou vago, vou tentar elucidar especificamente o seu problema:

o "b" na frente do objeto, indica que esse objeto é do tipo bytes, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
my_obj = b"abc123"
print(my_obj)
b'abc123'

print(type(my_obj))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Para "converte-lo" para string, voce precisa decodifica-lo, assim:

```
my_str = my_obj.decode("utf-8")
print(my_str)
abc123
print(type(my_str))
<class 'str'>
```

Como não estou envolvido com todo o seu contexto (vc teria que indicar os imports, no seu exemplo) acredito que vc teria que decodificar apos a decriptografia.

Talvez os exemplos abaixo possam "clarear" ainda mais:

```
item = "item1234"
print(item)
item1234

item = "item1234".encode("utf-8")
print(item)
b'item1234'

item = "item1234".encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")
print(item)
item1234
```

**Sugestão:** Tente sempre fazer a pergunta com um codigo que possa ser copiado e reproduzido da forma mais simples possivel para quem vai tentar ajudar, por exemplo, tente copiar o codigo que vc postou e reproduzir em um terminal python.

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver graças a ajuda de vocês.